# c++ parameter pack specification in constructor rather than template

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, class-template

Unlike function declarations with parameter packs, I've found that classes require the type for each argument in the angle brackets...

```
Component<IntegerPair, int, int> temp(40, 5);
```

...which seems redundant. Here's how I defined `Component`:

```
template<typename T, class... T_Args>
class Component
{
public:
  Component(T_Args... args)
    : m_data(args...)
  {}

  T m_data;
};
```

1. Is there a way to remove `int, int` from the above statement?
2. If so, is it **ok** to remove it?
3. Also, is my way of instantiation `m_data` safe? When using
   `std::forward<T_Args>(args)...` my compiler told me I didn't have a
   constructor that could convert all of the argument types.

Comment: You're basically asking if it's possible to deduce class template arguments from a constructor call - to which the asnwer is *no*. What you'll need is a "maker" function - like for example `std::make_pair` is, or a constructor template.

Comment: 3: you need to take in a universal reference `T_Args&&` to use perfect forwarding

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677505/why-cant-constructors-deduce-template-arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to make the constructor a template:

```
#include <utility>

struct IntegerPair {
    IntegerPair(int, int) {}
};

template<typename T>
class Component
{
public:
  template<typename... T_Args>
  Component(T_Args&&... args)
    : m_data(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...)
  {}

  T m_data;
};

int main()
{
    Component<IntegerPair> c {1,2};
}
```

This is functionally equivalent to `std::vector` and its member function `emplace_back`. It's perfectly ok, IMO. The error messages are pretty cryptic, as usual in template constructs like this, but this can be mitigated with an appropriate `static_assert`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, and you also fixed the forwarding. Why the curly braces for the arguments?

Comment: @user3097902 For no particular reason, it's newer syntax :) Parentheses would br equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

template parameter deduction only work for function calls so the basic pattern to achieve what you want looks like this:

```
template<typename T, class... T_Args>
Component<T, T_Args...> makeComponent(T_Args&&... args) {
   return Component<T, T_Args...>(std::forward<T_Args>(args)...);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto c = makeComponent<IntegerPair>(1, 1)
```